# Visual Studio Solution

Tags: vb.net, project, solution

My program adds files to a VB.NET solution. What I want is that the project, when files are added to it, is refreshes or prompted to refresh. Now what I am currently doing is unloading and reloading the project. This is fine, but I noticed that my newly added files are not included in the project, and I have to manually include them by clicking them.

How can I make my project add all files that are not included and refresh when new ones are added?

Thanks

My code to add.

[image]

Comment: I am adding them from a separate project, using File.WriteAllText

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. I have two different VB.NET projects. In one project, I am adding files to the other VB.NET project. Those files are not 'included' in the other project, so in order to include them I have to right click and hit "include".

Comment: And I add them programatically, not the normal way.

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228774%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN article

Comment: Because I am generating dynamic files (templates) that I am adding to my project. My other project is basically a tool that generates templates and adds them. Doing add existing item is manual and I want to automate that process

Comment: You have to edit the projet file, not only add them into the directory of the project I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of files can exist in folders and subfolders under the solution (sln file). not all of these files are required to participate in projects. each project file (vbproj / csproj) maintains the inventory of files *included* in the project. you need to both place your files at appropriate places **and** update the vbproj file appropriately.

As it happens, the vbproj files are not simple indexes, they are full blown build scripts. they have a pretty intricate file format (XML) and a convoluted semantics. Appending nodes in that file works fine if you follow the existing pattern. but i suggest you look up MSBUILD first.

Please note that if the project you are mutating programmatically, is open in visual studio, then there are strong chances of inconsistency. make sure the project is not open in any visual studio. programmatically altering the program itself (or the same project) is not advisable.